# Microsoft Azure Maps / Postman upload error

Tags: azure, http-status-code-401, azure-maps

I'm trying to upload my zip file for conversion for Azure maps using Postman and I have followed all the steps but I'm getting a WWW-Authenticate error in postman.

401 Unauthorized.
SharedKey realm="https://atlas.microsoft.com/, error="InvalidKey", error_description="The provided key was incorrect or the account resource does not exist."

I'm totally stumped as to why it's not working and have created another Azure resource, rotated my keys and still can not figure this out. Looking online I haven't found much help and don't really understand the issue.
If someone could give some help or advice that would be great.

Comment: Have you added your subscription key to your request? Have you created an Azure Maps creator resource within your Azure Maps account? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-creator

Comment: @rbrundritt Yea used the primary key from the azure maps authentication and also created an Azure maps creator resource.

Comment: @rbrundritt Yea used the primary key from the azure maps authentication and also created an Azure maps creator resource. 
Although looking at the documents now I've realized  that the post I was using is for United States and I'm in the UK so that might be my problem although I'm not 100% sure. 

https://us.atlas.microsoft.com/mapData?api-version=2.0&dataFormat=dwgzippackage&subscription-key={Azure-Maps-Primary-Subscription-key}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting an invalid key error because the brackets around the subscription-key query parameter was not removed?

Comment: Yep that was my problem lol Thanks for all your help!